# one line if else condition in python

Tags: python, conditional-statements

```
def sum10(a, b):
    if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0: return True; return False

print sum10(7, 3)
print sum10(-13, -17)
print sum10(3, 8)
```

the result is:

```
True
True
None
```

not what I expected:

```
True
True
False
```

any idea?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your code

```
def sum10(a, b):
    if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0: return True; return False
```

is equivalent to

```
def sum10(a, b):
    if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0: 
        return True; return False
```

so `return False` is never evaluated.

---

Some (of the probably endless) alternatives:

```
    if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0: 
        return True
    return False
```

or

```
    return sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0
```

or

```
    return True if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0 else False
```

or

```
    return False if (a+b) % 10 else True
```

or (the most readable IMHO)

```
    return not (a + b) % 10
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. Steak.  one more question, could you make your "Better use 1" to one line?

Comment: @yozloy I added more examples.

Answer (score 10):

This is what you want.

```
def sum10(a, b):
    return sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0
```

Also the ternary `If` in Python works like this

```
<True Statment> if <Conditional Expression> else <False Statement>
```

eg

```
True if sum([a,b]) % 10 == 0 else False
```

Might i also recommend using the plus operator?

```
True if (a+b) % 10 == 0 else False
```

Comment: Thanks for the ternary solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have if-else one liners, they should be written like this:

```
return True if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0 else False
```

Note the absence of two points in that one liner.

Comment: Thanks again for answering my question @alestanis, ternary is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `return False` is never executed due to it is into the if, not outside it.

So, when you take a true in the if condition, you are executing `return True`, but never the second statement.

Comment: +1 for good explanation of what it doesn't work, I think I should stick to ternary way

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum10(a, b):
    return sum([a, b])%10 == 0
```

Comment: Some explanation here would not go unappreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning True or False right away, you could try storing result in a boolean variable and then return that variable at the end. For example:

```
def sum(a,b):
  bool result
  if sum([a, b]) % 10 == 0:
    bool=True
  else:
    bool=False
  return bool
```